# ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:Python 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying

```
pip install pyaudio
```

But I got an error

```
Collecting pyaudio
```

Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
    Running setup.py install for pyaudio: started
    Running setup.py install for pyaudio: finished with status 'error'

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\AI\venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\pyaudio\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-9rgu21ro\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\AI\venv\include\site\python3.8\pyaudio'
     cwd: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pyaudio\
Complete output (17 lines):
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win32-3.8
copying src\pyaudio.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8
warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

running build_ext
building '_portaudio' extension
creating build\temp.win32-3.8
creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release
creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\src
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\AI\venv\include -IC:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\include -IC:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/_portaudiomodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.8\Release\src/_portaudiomodule.obj
_portaudiomodule.c
src/_portaudiomodule.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'portaudio.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.25.28610\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\AI\venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pyaudio\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\pyaudio\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-9rgu21ro\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\AI\venv\include\site\python3.8\pyaudio' Check the logs for full command output.

Answer (score 0):

You must use python versions 2.7, 3.4, 3.6 otherwise there will be an error.[supporting python versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vtLZ.png)

I downloaded this version 'https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2717/'  of python and it was able to install pyaudio.

[pyaudio installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIZNn.png)

If you have several versions of Python, then for example to run pip for Python 2.7.17 use this command: 
py -2 -m pip install pyaudio
[module pyaudio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mplti.png)